# The Stack Overflow logo seems a bit too low in the blog

Tags: discussion, design, logo, the-overflow

I get the impression when looking at the logos in [*The Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.blog/) blog's top right corner that the Stack Exchange logo stands out for being aligned slightly too low.

[image: Logos in the blog's top right corner]

(The strange thing is that every logo seems to have a different alignment anyway, but somehow the SO logo does stand out among the group. I suppose that kind of subtle and inconspicuous prominence can actually be considered good design.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is slightly too low. Opening developer tools gives us this:

[image]

As you can see, the image second from the right has a little bit too much space too! Nearly all images aren't centered properly (if the lines are correctly placed that is), including the SO icon. In terms of height centering, the SO icon should be booted up a few pixels up.

The "find something tool" seems to be poking out a little on the left side of it:

[image]

Unless of course, it didn't line up properly somehow when I opened it and simply shifting it leftwards a few pixels would center all the images.